# iOS app looks weird when running on device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

So, I followed the short tutorial from the website on how to create a simple app an iOS, "Phoneword". Developing it and testing it all worked fine, until I tried it out on my physical iPhone 6S Plus. It compiles and installs just fine, but when opening it, it looks completely wrong.

[This is how it looks inside of Visual Studio as iPhone 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQEkt.png)

[But on my physical device (or in iPhone 6 emulator)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Evc.png)

Am I missing something?

Thanks, Krax

Comment: Your issue looks like its with the Constraints in your story board.  You can read some on this here, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: which tutorial where you following? maybe it was to short...

Answer (score 0):

On Xamarin.iOS you can use [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) to position your views on the screen. You can use Auto Layout with storyboards, XIBs or even in code. Whichever way you prefer. (You did not specify in your question)